# Sharing handlers and backing beans

Tags: import, handler, javabeans, backing

I am wondering if it is possible to have a JSF handler and some of the backing beans in a war that is shared. I say war because I have a jsp which has a handler and backing beans that are shared between different applications, and need to be called by 2 different war files.

From my earlier investigation I found that it is not possible to have jsf fragments (.jsp and .jspf) in a jar, it has to be in a war. So I am thinking is it possible to put the common handler and beans in this war too and then import or somehow call the handler methods from the other war files.

I know it can be done easily if it was inside a jar file which is packaged in the war, but just wondering if instead of creating a separate jar file I can use the existing common war file.

Thanks. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to put the supporting code handlers and beans in the war as well. However since I need it to be called from 2 different wars it should be in a jar.

We decided to take a different approach anyways as this was not exactly successful.